# Read a provider inside a FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

When we need to read (not watch) a provider inside another one the documentation is clear:

"*DON'T CALL READ INSIDE THE BODY OF A PROVIDER*"

```
final myProvider = Provider((ref) {
  // Bad practice to call `read` here
  final value = ref.read(anotherProvider);
});
```

And it suggest to pass to the value exposed the Reader function: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers#can-i-read-a-provider-without-listening-to-it

```
final userTokenProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => null);

final repositoryProvider = Provider((ref) => Repository(ref.read));

class Repository {
  Repository(this.read);

  /// The `ref.read` function
  final Reader read;

  Future<Catalog> fetchCatalog() async {
    String token = read(userTokenProvider);

    final response = await dio.get('/path', queryParameters: {
      'token': token,
    });

    return Catalog.fromJson(response.data);
  }
}
```

And that's ok, but what is the best practice when I need to read a provider inside a `FutureProvider`?
I find myself in this situation many time because I expose the api as providers and inside the `FutureProvider` I call watch to get the api I need.
But I noticed that, because I'm watching the Api provider inside the `userProvider`, this won't gets disposed after been used.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to say:

### API CLASS

```
final userApiProvider = Provider((ref) => UserApi(ref.read));
class UserApi {

  final Dio _dio;

 const UserApi(Reader read): 
   _dio = read(dioProvider);

  Future<Response> getUser(String id, { CancelToken? cancelToken }) async{
    final _url = '$URL_TO_API/$id';
    return _dio.get(_url, cancelToken: cancelToken);
  }

}
```

### When using the API inside a FutureProvider

```
final userProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<User, int>((ref, userId) async {
  final userApi = **ref.watch(userApi);**
  final cancelToken = CancelToken();
  ref.onDispose(() { cancelToken.cancel(); });

  final user = await userApi.getUser(cancelToken: cancelToken);
  return user;
});
```

Comment: Have you try to add autoDispose to : final userApiProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) => UserApi(ref.read)); or StateProvider.autodispose. And to get your APi:     ref.watch(userApiProvider.notifier).getUser(cancelToken: cancelToken); Hope it help

Comment: Hi Mario, thank you. My apis provider are simple providers so they do not have .notifier but I will try to make them all autodispose and check that my future provider gets disposed accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The same logic applies.

By "Don't use `read` inside a provider", it isn't talking about the class `Provider` specifically, but *any* provider – so `FutureProvider` included.

In general, you should avoid using `read` as much as possible.

Comment: Hi Rémi, thank you. Yes of course that applies to every provider, but in the case of StateNotifierProvider you provided a way to not read inside of the provider body but instead pass the ref.read function to the notifier. In the case of future provider I found myself bound to use ref.watch and that make my future provider not disposing even if marked with auto dispose. I will try to make all my apis and my repositories autodispose as Mario stated out